# Using Propensity Score Matching to evaluate non randomized and fully implemented village fund program

Tags: econometrics

So i want to make a research about the impact of this program to community empowerment and infrastructure in villages. But the problem is the program itself (at the first year) implemented to almost all villages across countries. So can i use propensity score matching to evaluate this program?

So i have the data of villages level in 2014 (before the program is implemented) and villages level data in 2018 (after the program is implemented). Can i combine the data into cross-sectional and find the matching?

Thank you everyone:)

Comment: Who would you be matching?  You still need a group that was affected by the program, and a group unaffected by the program.

Comment: I want to match the village itself. if at 2018 all villages are affected by the program, can i match the village with the data at 2014 (all village unaffected) and searching for nearest neighbor with same characteristics?

Comment: If you do it, it means you are comparing villages in 2018 to similar ones in 2014. You can identify "treatment effect + period effect", but I wonder how you could identify the treatment effect separately. You need some means to identify the period effects. (In DID this is achieved by using the control group, but you have no control group.) Sorry but it doesn't look promising to me.

Comment: yeah. i know that the potential bias that i need to overcome is the period effect itself. i think i could reduce the problem of period effect by matching not only with local characteristics but also with larger level economic condition such as inflation, economic growth and so on in district or sub disctrict level? But thanks for the comment:)

I know that this is not such an promising research. But only those data that available and i don't know which method should i use to evaluate it impact.

Comment: I can imagine your troubles (and I do appreciate your efforts to overcome the problems with the given data). If you have _multiple years_ before and after the treatment, you could consider controlling for the time heterogeneity by including some variables (possibly time series variables). If you have only "before" and "after", well, you may have to rely on your artistic sense of modeling and persuade your potential critics. Good luck! I am interested in what you would come up with.